# xPath: get parent and second following sibling

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a huge XML where I need to locate the amount to pay. It is located 2 cells away from the cell with `CellText = 'amount'`

```
<TableRow>
    <Cell>
       <RowNo>4</RowNo>
       <CellColNo>1</CellColNo>
       <CellText>amount</CellText>
       <CellAttribute/>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
       <RowNo>4</RowNo>
       <CellColNo>2</CellColNo>
       <CellText/>
       <CellAttribute/>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
       <RowNo>4</RowNo>
       <CellColNo>3</CellColNo>
       <CellText>138</CellText>
       <CellAttribute/>
    </Cell>
</TableRow>
```

Code, where I am struggling how to build the expressionString:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String exprString = 
 "//TableRow/Cell[CellText='amount:']/following-sibling::cell[2]CellText/text()";
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(exprString);

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(j).getNodeValue());
}
```

How do I create the correct `exprString`?

Comment: is it correct that it is the following sibling? or should it be the following sibling of the parent?

Comment: Maybe if you spelled `Cell` in mixed-case and added the missing `/` it would work? `following-sibling::Cell[2]/CellText`

Comment: @Andreas you made my day!

as simple as that ;)

Answer (score 13):

An XPath expression that you could use is as follows:

```
TableRow/Cell/CellText[text()='amount']/parent::Cell/following-sibling::Cell[2]/CellText/text()
```

**[XPathFiddle example](http://xpathfiddle.net/E67N5S)**

This will:

- select the `CellText` element with text equal to `amount`
- then navigate to its parent `Cell` element
- then navigate to its 2nd following `Cell` sibling
- return the text from the `CellText` child

**Output**

138

Comment: FYI link is broken.