# xPath retrieve multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath, nodelist

I have a huge xml where I need to locate the amount to pay and corresponding the billID.

I just figured out how to select the correct amount (located 2 cells away from the cell with CellText = 'amount'). I can print this, and it works.

Now I also need to print the corresponding billID. How do I do that?

This is an example of the type of XML I am using:

```
<Section>
<Item>
    <TableRow>
        <Cell>
           <RowNo>4</RowNo>
           <CellColNo>1</CellColNo>
           <CellText>amount</CellText>
           <CellAttribute/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
           <RowNo>4</RowNo>
           <CellColNo>2</CellColNo>
           <CellText/>
           <CellAttribute/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
           <RowNo>4</RowNo>
           <CellColNo>3</CellColNo>
           <CellText>138</CellText>
           <CellAttribute/>
        </Cell>
    </TableRow>
</Item>
<Item>
    <BillID>123456</BillID>
</Item>
</Section>
<Section>
...
</Section>
```

this is my code, where I need to **add that the billID also should be printed**:

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String exprString = "//TableRow/Cell[CellText='amount:']/following-sibling::cell[2]CellText/text()";
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(exprString);

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(j).getNodeValue());
    }
```

(I know the XML doesnt make sense, its just to illustrate the format. There are as well several "Sections", so I need to make sure I select the right one!). Thanks in advance!

Comment: and of course there are several node objects, so Id really like to select the right one!

Comment: You should prefer to add additional information to your question via edits instead of writing comments.

Comment: done! can you help me with an answer now as you took the time to comment ;)

Comment: No. But I can link to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35710333/1305969). It looks nearly identical to your's.

Comment: yeah but this is the problem that follows...

Answer (score 2):

If you like to get both `String`s, you can use the following XPath expression applying the node unification operator `|` relative to a hypothetical `root` node:

```
/root/Section/Item/TableRow/Cell/CellText[text()='amount']/parent::Cell/following-sibling::Cell[2]/CellText/text() | /root/Section/Item/BillID/text()
```

which can checked [here at XPathFiddle](http://xpathfiddle.net/U2831L).
This results in

> 138
>   123456

Answer (score 0):

This snippet would do it. From the node where you select the amount, find the ancestor `Item` node, go to the next sibling and select the `BillID` text. This uses the following XPath once the amount is selected:

```
ancestor::Item[1]/following-sibling::Item[1]/BillID/text()
```

---

```java
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class GetTheBillId {
    private static final String xml1=
"<root>"+
"<Item>"+
"    <TableRow>"+
"        <Cell>"+
"           <RowNo>4</RowNo>"+
"           <CellColNo>1</CellColNo>"+
"           <CellText>amount</CellText>"+
"           <CellAttribute/>"+
"        </Cell>"+
"        <Cell>"+
"           <RowNo>4</RowNo>"+
"           <CellColNo>2</CellColNo>"+
"           <CellText/>"+
"           <CellAttribute/>"+
"        </Cell>"+
"        <Cell>"+
"           <RowNo>4</RowNo>"+
"           <CellColNo>3</CellColNo>"+
"           <CellText>138</CellText>"+
"           <CellAttribute/>"+
"        </Cell>"+
"    </TableRow>"+
"</Item>"+
"<Item>"+
"    <BillID>123456</BillID>"+
"</Item>"+
"</root>";

    private static final String xpathExpr1=
"//TableRow/Cell[CellText='amount']/following-sibling::Cell[2]/CellText/text()";

    private static final String xpathExpr2=
"ancestor::Item[1]/following-sibling::Item[1]/BillID/text()";   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile(xpathExpr1);
            XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile(xpathExpr2);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expr1.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml1)),XPathConstants.NODESET);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for( int i = 0; i != nodeList.getLength(); ++i ) {
                Node n = (Node) nodeList.item(i);
                sb.append( "Amount=" ).append(n.getNodeValue());

                Node billId = (Node) expr2.evaluate(n,XPathConstants.NODE); // search for Bill ID
                sb.append("; BillId=").append(billId.getNodeValue());
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Amount=138; BillId=123456
```